# .htaccess URL rewrite does not work

Tags: .htaccess

I've wrote .htaccess file to convert urls to SEO friendly :

the original url is :

```
http://palestinianz.com/?page=person&p=Alex-Atalla
```

the content of .htaccess is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=person&p=$1 [L]
```

it should produce a link like this  :

```
http://palestinianz.com/Alex-Atalla.html
```

But it makes no effect although I put the file in the root of my website !
where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the URL to change in the address bar, you need to redirect the browser, then rewrite on the server. The first part of this answer explains the process that you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273

So looking at the second list, the process is to redirect the browser if an ugly link is request to a nice looking link:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?page=person&p=([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

Now, on the server end you need to internall rewrite it back to the ugly url, which is more or less what you already have:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=person&p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ ./index.php?page=person&p=$1 [L]
```

Only problem with this is any `.html` page will go through this. May want to change to the following:

```
 # URL: domain.com/person/Alex-Atalla.html

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/(.+)\.html$
 RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)\.html$ ./index.php?page=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

This will allow you to have more robustness in changing the the page variable as well

Comment: this code 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=person&p=$1 [L] working well except it does not change the url in the address bar, I mean after adding the .htaccess both : 
http://palestinianz.com/Alex-Atalla.html and 
http://palestinianz.com/?page=person&p=Alex-Atalla are working 

but the problem is the url remains like : http://palestinianz.com/?page=person&p=Alex-Atalla in the address bar !!