# Convert URLs to SEO friendly urls

Tags: .htaccess

How can I convert my urls to SEO friendly URLS using .htaccess ?

the orginal url like this :

```
http://palestinianz.com/?page=person&p=10
```

and

```
http://palestinianz.com/?page=persons&c=10
```

the rewritten URL for the first link is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

the result of the first link :

```
http://palestinianz.com/person/10.html
```

how can I write a redirect rule to the rewritten url !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to apply [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745914/851273), changing the `person` to `persons` and the `p` to `c`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?page=persons&c=([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /persons/%1.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?page=person&p=([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /person/%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

and back

```
RewriteRule ^persons/([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=persons&c=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^person/([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=person&p=$1 [L]
```