# mod_rewrite doesn't work both directions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I get an **original url**:
**www.mydomain.com/menu/?myid=29&mypage=pizza-hut.html**

with the following mod_rewrite code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^menu/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /menu/?pid=$1&alias=$2 [L]
```

I get this nice url:
**www.mydomain.com/menu/29/pizza-hut.html**

so, both url above reference the same page...right!
now the real deal is,

WHY when I type the url,the original one:

**www.mydomain.com/menu/?myid=29&mypage=pizza-hut.html**

***it doesn't redirect to***

**www.mydomain.com/menu/29/pizza-hut.html**

it keeps its original one in the address bar, is there any line I should add?

Comment: Because: see the explanation at the beginning of this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, all the links you generate should be the nice urls. Don't have links like `/menu/?myid=29&mypage=pizza-hut.html` in any of your pages. Use the clean URLs that you've ensured to route correctly on the back end that look like this: `www.mydomain.com/menu/29/pizza-hut.html`

The rules that you have rewrite on the server the nice looking urls to what your content understands (e.g. `/menu/?myid=29&mypage=pizza-hut.html`). That's the most important part. If you want to correct all the direct requests for the ugly URLs, you need to first make sure all your pages start using the nice looking ones, then you can maybe do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /menu/?\?myid=([^&]+)&mypage=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^menu/?$ /menu/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: yes...to use clean URL in all links I have would be the simplest way and conceal the ugly URL. Let me see what I can do with the references you've given me. thanks.

Comment: Hi @jon-lin I got this code working:  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /menu/?\?myid=([^&]+)&mypage=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^menu/?$ /menu/%1/%2.\html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^menu/([0-9]+)/(.+)/$\.html /menu/?myid=$1&mypage=$2 [L] . BUT It seems followed by some query such this: www.mydomain.com/menu/29/pizza-hut.html?myid=29&mypage=pizza-hut.html It seem something to do with QSA ?

Comment: @Gregory Sorry, I was missing a **?** at the end of the rule. It needs to read `RewriteRule ^menu/?$ /menu/%1/%2? [R=301,L]`, note the `?` at the end of `%1/%2`

Comment: That "?" DOES the magic !! thank you, you're the man..I should give you 5 stars for this

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /menu/?\?myid=([^&]+)&mypage=([^&\ ]+) 
RewriteRule ^menu/?$ /menu/%1/%2.\html? [R=301,L]
```

Note the `?` following the `.\html`