# htaccess remove only '?' sign from URL with query string

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, ssi

How to remove `?` sign from URL with query string

Comment: Search google for mod_rewrite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

# This is to physically change what's in the browser's address bar using a client redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R=301,L]

# This is to internally rewrite on the server side
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /?$1 [L]
```

---

> Also please could you explain me what does mean `[A-Z]{3,9}\ and ([^\ ]+)` on its own? Where I can read about building this type of structures?

That regular expression is used to match the *HTTP Request*, the first line is going to look something like this:

```
GET /path/to/file HTTP/1.1
```

The first word is the **METHOD**, which can be anywhere between 3 to 9 characters long (thus the `{3,9}`, the second word is the *unaltered* URI of the request. This is what goes through the rewrite engine, but before any path processing is done on it. The last bit is the protocol version and is somewhat optional, and determines whether there will be headers afterwards.

Comment: Not working. I get Internal Server Error after applying string: RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1 [L]

Comment: @user1586029 Sorry, I forgot the `?` at the end of the rule's target

Comment: Mmm, I really appreciate you efforts for me. But seems results still not so great. If I type http://mysite.com?page in browser address field I get under Chrome, Firefox and IE http://mysite.com/?page, so the same question sign is still there. Opera gives me http://mysite.compage/, Safari gives http://test.metal.by/page/ I can't get what's the problem with that.

Comment: @user1586029 There's 2 things that one could mean when one says "I have this URL, I want this URL". Typically it means you've got some URL that you are generating and it needs to be rewritten internally to something that can process the "pretty urls". If you want to **redirect the browser** (physically change what the URL address bar says), then that's a completely different thing. I've edited the answer to include that. See explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273

Comment: Thank you for the link. It was helpful. I read it and figured out code. Please take a look at that and correct what I've done wrong. Seems code is mostly working but my server now doesn't get query string value. Please look again at first post. I edited this and tried to describe there situation in details according updated conditions. Also please could you explain me what does mean [A-Z]{3,9}\ and ([^\ ]+) on its own? Where I can read about building this type of structures?

Comment: @user1586029 Please see my edit, there was a mistake in my rules, try them again, and also see explanmation

Comment: Seems that string `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /?$1 [L]` gives Internal Server Error. Cause if I comment that error disappears. I think the problem is slash here `^/?(.*)$`. But on the other side without slash rule doesn't work.

Comment: @user1586029 Yeah, that `(.*)` should be a `(.+)`

Comment: Awesome! That's working now with query string at least in all browsers. But few small problems appear. See first I have simple test tag `<img src=http://domain.tld/image/image.png>` and image is not loading on the page after applying new `RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /?$1 [L]`. The second and I think relative to first is that when I type URL `http://domain.tld/page/page.html` it can't be open I get error in the SSI include like `[an error occurred while processing this directive]` instead of opening simple HTML page that I have on the server.

Comment: Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` right before the last rewrite rule.

Comment: Great! The rule on itself is working now. I tested that with other rules and I have a one conflict with `.html` extension removing rule `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ \/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \/$1.html [L]` What problem could be here? So finally everything's working now. But I want open `http://domain.tld/page/page.html` by typing address without extension `http://domain.tld/page/page`

Comment: @user1586029 no clue what `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$` is for, but this doesn't even seem to be about the original question anymore and putting code in comments just look like gibberish. This still an issue with **htaccess remove only '?'sing from URL with QUERY_STRING**?

Comment: So you're right. I understand you that I should ask new question. Right? Jon thank you very much for helping me removing this question sign from query string. I'm very very happy with result. What I can do for you to show my gratitude?

Comment: @user1586029 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work You should also ask a new question because talking like this in comments will get the answer **flagged**, asking new questions inside comments exacerbates it. Also, asking a new question allows you you clearly describe the problem in more than 500 characters, allows you to format code so that it is readable, and allows others to post answers, which are more than 500 characters, and they can format code so it's readable.