# htaccess won't rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ product.php?id=$1&srl=$2&item=$3&page=$4&title=$5#titleProduct
```

When I hit f5 button for refresh, the URL remains and it's not rewrited. I tried to access with the "new" rewrited link, but it's not working.

Comment: did you check AccessFileName in your main conf file if it's not set to something else?

Comment: Currently I'm using a free web host service. Where can I find this file?

Comment: you probably won't have access to apache2 config files than. Ask your provider if you are able to use .htaccess files.

Comment: **"When I hit f5 button for refresh, the URL remains and it's not rewrited."** What URL did you type in the address bar? What does hitting F5 supposed to accomplish (you do know that rewrites are entirely internal to the server, right?)

Comment: Wow, that means I'm need to update every single file for the "new" rewrite? All files contains different hyperlinks with the "old" link. I thought if I write a .htaccess file, all url will automatically rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wow, that means I'm need to update every single file for the "new" rewrite? All files contains different hyperlinks with the "old" link. I thought if I write a .htaccess file, all url will automatically rewrite.

You're thinking of a browser redirect, that changes the address bar, a rewrite takes the nicer looking URL and internally rewrites the URI to something the server can understand. See the top half of [this answer for a better explanation of this process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273).

So you can do a browser redirect if the browser actually requests the `product.php` file, then *redirect* to the fake nice looking URL. The browser will then resend a new request, for the nice looking URL and the server gets that, internally rewrites it *back* to the php file (the rule that you have).

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /product\.php\?id=([^&]+)&srl=([^&]+)&item=([^&]+)&page=([^&]+)&title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^product.php$ /product/%1/%2/%3/%4/%5/ [L,R=301]
```

This will take a `/product.php\?id=123&srl=abc&item=qwerty&page=blah&title=something` URI and redirect the browser with a 301 to the nicer looking URL. Then you're rule should internally rewrite it back.

Regardless, you really should change the links you serve to the nicer URLs, relying on mod_rewrite to do both ends of the work is *really* inefficient.