# using .htaccess file i want to edit url

Tags: php, .htaccess

my url is

http://altikalti.com/down.php?folderpath=53/143&imageid=29&file=17Mar2014-murzuq-band-ghat-festival-libya(altikalti.com).jpg&new

output url:

http://altikalti.com/53/143/29/17Mar2014-murzuq-band-ghat-festival-libya(altikalti.com).jpg

How can i do.. if any changes in panel setting then you can also suggest me
thank u for reading...
Have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create .htaccess file into root folder (e.g. http://altikalti.com/ location)

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) http://altikalti.com/down.php folderpath=$1/$2&imageid=$3&file=$4&new [L]
```

If you're not in production environment, you can check if mod-rewrite is enabled by

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.google.com/ [L, R=301]
```

If it work every request should be redirect to google.com, which mean the first script should work and do the job for you.

Comment: its not work in cpanel

Comment: create .htaccess file with the content above and put it into your web root. (You can use file manager in Cpanel to do this)

Comment: i have created but its not overrite url..

Comment: any type of setting changes required to change url?

Comment: I edited the answer. .htaccess require mod rewrite module enabled.

Comment: i am already set there but its not work

Comment: It might be that you don't have mod_rewrite module enabled on your server. Sorry I can't help you from here, you may need to contact your server support directly.

Comment: its ok ..but in localhost how can i use

Comment: Assuming that you running xampp
http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/

Comment: Yes thare is xampp.. and all setting which you seggest that is bydefault setted then how can i use urlrewriting

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked several times already.

By searching with the keywords `friendly url htaccess` you can find this discussion that give an answer on the subject :

[Friendly Url .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061699/friendly-url-htaccess)

Or this one, especially for images :

[Friendly URL for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963617/friendly-url-for-images)

You can still follow this blog post for more complete examples :

http://surefirewebservices.com/tutorials/friendly-url-tutorial-pt1