# Having much trouble with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some problems in my `.htaccess` file.

I would like to display the content of this URL:

```
http://mywebsite.com/admin/payments/invoices/view/index.php?id=123456
```

When I access this one:

```
http://mywebsite.com/admin/payments/invoices/view/123456/
```

Here's my actual .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/payments/invoices/
RewriteRule ^/view/([0-9]+)/(index.php)?$ /view/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do have the `view` directory, then the easiest thing is to put this `.htaccess` *in that directory* (i.e. `{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin/payments/invoices/view/.htaccess`):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /admin/payments/invoices/view
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$  index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The index.php in the left side hand of the `RewriteRule` is not required (actually, I expect it not to work: the `DirectoryIndex` should not yet have been injected in the URI at this stage - unless some other `RewriteRule` is in effect?), nor is the / at the end of the `RewriteBase`.

I tested the above on Apache/2.2.21, but the module rules are the same for later versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*admin/payments/invoices/view/index\.php\?id=([0-9]+) admin/payments/invoices/view/$1/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can't match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`

Comment: I see, I didn't know that. I will try to update the answer, but I am not sure how to extract that value using htaccess. Probably it would be good to create a dummy `index.php` file and redirect the client in PHP using `header`. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^admin/payments/invoices/view/index\.php$ /admin/payments/invoices/view/%1/index.php [L]
```

So when you enter `http://mywebsite.com/admin/payments/invoices/view/index.php?id=123456` in your browser's URL address bar, you will get served the content at `/admin/payments/invoices/view/123456/index.php`. [Since it's completely unclear what you actually want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273), in case you wanted it the other way around:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin/payments/invoices/view/([0-9]+)/(index.php)?$ /admin/payments/invoices/view/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: @Mathieu then you want the second one

Comment: @JonLin It looks my previous comment wasn't sent correctly. I almost found how to make it, but it seriously needs improvements: `RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$  
RewriteRule ^index.php$ %1/? [R=301,L]`  
But when I enter http://mywebsite.com/admin/payments/invoices/view/index.php?id=563052  
I'm given: http://mywebsite.com/www/mywebsite.com/admin/payments/invoices/view/563052/  
It's almost that but I'm still not where I wanted xD