# mod_rewrite so that first-level subdirectory is a GET variable

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Alright, title is REALLY sloppy.

Here's my problem: I have a news site and when you go to the main page (`domain.com`) it redirects you to `domain.com/news/top?geography=San_Francisco` after it figures out your geography.

How do I use the .htaccess so that it goes from `domain.com/news/top?geography=San_Francisco domain.com/San_Francisco/news/top`  ?

There are some similar questions, but I have not found one similar enough in that you're editing the URL as a furtherback subdirectory.

It should also be noted that I am using the Code Igniter framework for PHP and it normally has it as `domain.com/index.php/news/top?geography=San_Francisco` but I did a mod_rewrite already to get rid of the `index.php`.  The code is as follows for that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Code I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/news/top$ /news/top?geography=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the index.php rule that you have, try adding this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/news/top$ /news/top?geography=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You'll need to make sure the links you generate are in the form of `domain.com/San_Francisco/news/top` though.

---

But to take care of the links in the wild that still look like the old way, you have to match against the actual request:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /news/top\?geography=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^news/top$ /%1/news/top? [L,R=301]
```

This will 301 redirect the browser if someone goes to the link `domain.com/news/top?geography=San_Francisco` and make it so the browser's address bar says this: `domain.com/San_Francisco/news/top`. At which point the browser will send another request for the second URL, and you use the rule above to change it back into the one with a query string.

Comment: The problem that I'm now receiving is that CodeIgniter is now thinking that, due to its functionality, LA is actually a controller and it says that the controller (San_Francisco) doesn't exist.


From what I know about this stuff (very little), is there a way to see if there is a /news/ in the URL and if there is then take the GET variable and put it before the /news/?


Now, this might be completely and utterly wrong as I've only been going over this for an hour, but couldn't be something such as:

`code`: RewriteRule ^(.*)$/news/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /news/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)?geography=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @user1390561 are you trying to generate links to look like `domain.com/San_Francisco/news/top`? You seemed to be asking for the other way around. The concept of **I want to turn this URL, to this URL** really makes zero sense, since you can't magically change URLs in the wild.

Comment: Yea, so I'm trying to take a URL of domain.com/news/top?geography=San_Francisco and turn it into domain.com/San_Francisco/news/top.

If that's not possible (aside from being insanely embarrassed), I'm assuming it's at least possible to turn it into domain.com/news/top/san_francisco?

Comment: @user1390561 it isn't anything to be embarrassed about, it isn't something simple to conceptualize, [the top part of my answer here tries to explain some of it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273). I've edited my answer to account for the browser part.