# Redirect of rewrite url with parameters based on one value

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an events page that I need to redirect or rewrite based on a value in the url.

The page generates urls like:

```
www.website.com/booking/?event=value1&date=value2&noa=value3
```

I would like this to redirect based on the first value regardless of what comes after so if `event=new-event` it would redirect to:

```
www.website.com/booking/value-1
```

Comment: We're happy to help you out if you get stuck, but this is not a "write htaccess rules for free"-site. Please share what you've got so far and explain where exactly you're stuck. In addition, your question is unclear as it's using "redirect" and "rewrite" interchangeably. [Those terms are **not** interchangeable!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399505/understanding-difference-between-redirect-and-rewrite-htacess)

Comment: I understand that this is not a "write htaccess rules for free" site but I really had nothing to add as all of my Googling has not helped my understanding and I don't think it is smart to mess around with ht access unless I am sure of result.

As for using redirect and rewrite interchangeably - that was because I am unsure of which one would be better to use.

Answer (score 0):

C# Code behind:

```
Resoponse.Redirect("<Your Base URL>/booking/" + Request.Params["event"]);
```