# Why POST don't work with some rewrite conditions in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, post, mod-rewrite

All $_POST do not work with this .htaccess code in place:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

// ========================== this code too is in place, but it seems not to impact on $_POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
// =================================================
```

Any idea on why such a problem? What can I do to solve and get the same result for php extensions?

Comment: `R=301` is a redirect. If you send a POST request to that URL, the web server will redirect the request (using GET) to the new URL and all posted data will be removed (since GET requests doesn't support anything in the body of the request). The second rule is a rewrite, which isn't the same thing as a redirect. You can more about the differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399668/2453432

Comment: You can try to use `R=308` instead. That's also a permanent redirect, but it tells the client to use the same http method. Not sure how widely used/implemented it is though.

Comment: @Magnus - Your suggestion works. But about what you said, would you expect any "collateral effect"?

Comment: No, not really. If someone has issues with it, it's mostly poorly written clients that doesn't follow the standards and to be honest, we shouldn't care about those.

Comment: Given that, I agree. Thank you, so

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You should add that as an answer. In addition, the OP shouldn't be sending POST requests to the non-canonical URL to begin with. (A 308 is widely supported.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R=301` is a redirect. If you send a POST request to that URL, the web server will redirect the request (using GET) to the new URL and all posted data will be removed (since GET requests doesn't support anything in the body of the request).

The second rule is a rewrite, which isn't the same thing as a redirect.

You can more about the differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399668/2453432

#### Solution

Use `R=308` instead. That is also a permanent redirect but it tells the client to use the same http method for the new request.