# htaccess dynamic url redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following URL

```
https://example.com/expert-profile?id=john-doe&locale=en
```

I want it to be redirected to

```
https://example.com/expert/john-doe
```

I tried the following

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)id=([^&]+)&?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^expert-profile$ https://example.com/expert/%3?%1%4 [L,R=301]
```

And a couple of other solutions, nothing is working here. Can someone help me to go in the right direction?

**Update:**

This is my current `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>

Redirect 301 "/en/download-app" "/download-app"
```

Comment: What exactly was happening with the attempt that you've posted? It should result in a "valid" redirect (albeit with an additional query string). If nothing at all is happening then you're probably putting the directive in the wrong place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please keep your htaccess file in your root and have it in following way.
Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)&locale=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-.*/?$ $1/%1-%2 [R=301,L]
```

---

---

***OR*** in case you don't have Rules to handle non-existing files/directories then use following Rules set. Please make sure either use above OR following Rules set one at a time only.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)&locale=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-.*/?$ $1/%1-%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:expert)/([^-]*)-(.*)$ $1-profile?id=$1&locale=$2 [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

Comment: I tried and it is not working. I have update my question with the content of my current htaccss files, where am I going wrong here?

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar, Ok, could you please confirm that you are hitting `https://example.com/expert-profile?id=john-doe&locale=en` link in your browser?

Comment: I do confirm, I am hitting the right URL. The other rule of download-app I have is working perfectly fine

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar, if this is the url `https://example.com/expert-profile?id=john-doe&locale=en` you are hitting then please try my 2nd set of Rules once and let me know then(I added your shown rules also now in it), let me know how it goes.

Comment: Let me check and get back in a while. Thank you.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar, sure, let's hope for the BEST, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want it rewritten, capture the name `(.+)` and insert it into the target `$1`

```
RewriteRule ^expert/(.+)$ /expert-profile?id=$1&locale=en [L]
```

And don't use flag [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) here, unless you really want a [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12399505/1741542).---

---

To redirect from `expert-profile?id=john-doe` to `expert/john-doe`, capture the id `(.+?)` from the query string and insert it in the substitution URL `%1`

```
RewriteCond &%{QUERY_STRING}& &id=(.+?)&
RewriteRule ^expert-profile$ /expert/%1 [R,L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` ([permanent redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)).

Don't use both rules together. If you do, it will result in an endless redirect loop and finally give a "500 Internal Server Error".

---

Unrelated, but *never* test with [`R=301`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)!

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar What URL do you enter in your browser? Is it `https://example.com/expert/john-doe`, or is it `https://example.com/expert-profile?id=john-doe&locale=en`?

Comment: This is the url I tried https://example.com/expert-profile?id=john-doe&locale=en

Answer (score 2):

> I have following URL
>
> ```
> https://example.com/expert-profile?id=john-doe&locale=en
> ```
>
> I want it to be redirected to
>
> ```
> https://example.com/expert/john-doe
> ```

You would need to do something like the following at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file, *before* your existing directives (order is important):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^expert-profile$ /expert/%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

This captures the value of the `id` URL parameter (in the `%1` backreference) regardless of where it appears in the query string and discards all other URL parameters. I'm assuming you don't specifically need to match `locale=en`?

Note that the regex subpattern `([^&]+)` (the `id` *value*) only matches *something*, not *nothing*. If the URL parameter is empty (ie. `id=&locale=en`) then no redirect occurs.

The `QSD` flag is necessary to discard the original query string.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. And clear your browser cache before testing. Only use a 301 (permanent) redirect if this really is intended to be *permanent*.

To redirect the specific URL `/expert-profile?id=<name>&locale=en` to `/expert/<name>`, ie. the `id` parameter is at the start of the query string and is followed by `locale=en` only then you can (and should) be more specific in the *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)&locale=en$
RewriteRule ^expert-profile$ /expert/%1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)id=([^&]+)&?(.*)?$
> RewriteRule ^expert-profile$ https://example.com/expert/%3?%1%4 [L,R=301]
> ```

This is close (providing you placed the rule at the top of the file), however, this tries to preserve the other URL parameters, ie. `locale=en` and whatever else, to create another query string - which you've not stated in your requirements.

---

*Aside:* The existing answers are *assuming* you are wanting to *internally rewrite* (URL rewrite) the request in the other direction, ie. from `/expert/john-doe` to `/expert-profile?id=john-doe&locale=en`. This is probably due to how questions of this nature are notoriously miswritten and this is often the real underlying *intention*. However,  you've made no mention of this here and a URL of the form `/expert-profile` is not a valid endpoint - so it wouldn't really make sense to "rewrite" the URL in that direction. (?)