# regex in my RewriteRule is OK, but .htaccess does not work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm having a lot of trouble getting my .htaccess ReWrite to work on my apache web server.  I've read several tutorials and tested my regex matching with Grep.

Here is the code:

```
    RewriteRule \?action=viewArticle&articleId=([0-9]*)&categoryId=([0-9])$ essays/$1 [R=301,L]
```

here is a url I'm trying to match:

```
http://mysite.com/?action=viewArticle&articleId=15&categoryId=1
```

and change to

```
http://mysite.com/essays/15
```

UPDATE: Solution! with a very [excellent tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709634/convert-original-url-to-friendly-url/11711948#11711948) from Jon.  It was very important that I put `<base href="/">` in my header file to get the css to work correctly.

Final rewrite looked like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /?action=viewArticle&articleId=([0-9]*)&categoryId=([0-9])
RewriteRule ^$ /essays/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^essays/([0-9]+) /?action=viewArticle&articleId=$1&categoryId=([0-9]) [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't match hosts or query strings inside a `RewriteRule`, you need to match against the `%{HTTP_HOST}` and `%{QUERY_STRING}` variables in a `RewriteCond` directive:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=viewArticle&articleId=([0-9]*)&categoryId=([0-9])$
RewriteRule ^$ /essays/%1? [L,R=301]
```

This redirects the browser (changing the URL in the address bar) when someone goes to `http://mysite.com/?action=viewArticle&articleId=15&categoryId=1` to `http://mysite.com/essays/15`

You don't need the `%{HTTP_HOST}` condition if your htaccess file only serves a single host.

Comment: Wow, thanks @Jon.  That almost works, the problem is that now a) it sends me to http://mysite.com/essays/15?action=viewArticle&articleId=15&categoryId=1 and b) it generates an error page

Comment: @Dave Sorry, I left out the `?` after `/essays/%1`. That removes the query string. As for the error page, what's the error you get? Is it a not found (404) or a server error (500)?

Comment: @ Jon, no prob, thanks so much for the help.  the `?` fixed problem one.  The error is a not found

Comment: @Dave So if you type `http://mysite.com/essays/15` in your URL address bar, that doesn't return a 404?

Comment: @Dave But in your question, you want the above to be redirected to `http://mysite.com/essays/15`, why would you redirect it to a resource that doesn't exist (or doesn't have any way of serving the request)?

Comment: because I'm a novice... I was hoping to use mod_rewrite to clean up my urls.  I didn't realize that the redirect was more than a cosmetic modification

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16900/discussion-between-dave-and-jon-lin)