# Got stuck in a very basic .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
<h1><a href="profile.php?id=' . $id . '" target="_self">' . $name. '</a></h1>
```

The above is the reference which points to my profile1.php file. This file is called index.php . It currently displays the urls as this:

http://www.domain.com/interact/profile1.php?id=36

I have tried implementing the .htaccess file to rewrite the url. I tried many combinations and most of them gave a 500 error and some did not rewrite the url.
This is the .htaccess file which I use, it does not make the url to change.

I want the url to look like http://www.domain.com/interact/profile/36

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile1.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I know this is a very basic question but I seem to stuck in it and have read basic tutorials but am not able to implement it properly.

The files index.php ,profile1.php and .htaccess are in folder named interact.

Tell me any changes required in php or .htaccess files.

Comment: "**I have tried implementing the .htaccess file to rewrite the url**", to what? it's not clear what you're trying to do or what your question is. Is it that [you're confusing rewrite and redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273)?

Comment: @JonLin I forgot to write the url. I have edited the question with the new url I want to rewrite to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It currently displays the urls as this: **`http://www.domain.com/interact/profile1.php?id=36`**
>
> ...
>
> I want the url to look like **`http://www.domain.com/interact/profile/36`**

### Step 1:

Change your content to have links like this:

```
<h1><a href="profile/' . $id . '" target="_self">' . $name. '</a></h1>
```

This way, when you click on a link the URL that will appear in the URL address bar is will look like: **`http://www.domain.com/interact/profile/36`**

### Step 2:

Then you need to use these rules to internally change it back:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /interact/
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]*) profile1.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

In order to point any external links, like google index bots to the new URLs, you'll need to add these as well:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /interact/profile1\.php\?id=([0-9]*)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/interact/profile/%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: okay thats works fine for the page and is rewriting the url but it is messing up my css. My css files are not in the same directory as the profile1.php or index.php . It is in www.domain.com/css. How to make the css correct.

Comment: @hritikwatts you need to add `<base href="/interact/">` in the header of your profile page.

Comment: With the line you gave RewriteBase /interact/ it is giving the desired url but is giving object not found error but on removing the line it works fine. And where to add this <base> ?

Comment: okay thats neat I put the <base> tag with full url in the head and voila its done. Thanks accepted.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  RewriteRule ^interact/profile1.php/(.*)$ interact/profile1.php?id=$1 [L]
```

i don't know what make QSA modifiers does so i remove it. If you know what, use it)

Comment: does not work.I think some changes might also be needed in the php file with which I am referencing the profile1.php file.

Comment: @hritikwatts that's a little strange because it work for me great. The trick is that the left part is that you want to show to users in the url and right part is that you will show to server part. In your question RewriteRule is wrong, or may be i don't understood what you want to do.

Comment: so how do you send the reference to the variables to show it as

interact/profile/34 , because for me I have shown the code above and profile1.php accepts the variable using isset .What am I doing wrong?