# How would I setup a URL rewrite for this?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I tried a few different things, but came up unsuccessful.

Basically, I've got some very ugly urls.

```
http://example.com/index.php?p=1_4_Contact-Us
http://backlinktuners.com/index.php?p=1_2_Services
```

I would like them to just be simple like,

```
http://example.com/contact-us
```

How would I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear (since asking a URL *to be* some other URL doesn't make any sense in this context), it sounds like you're asking for a client redirect, meaning when someone enters `http://backlinktuners.com/index.php?p=1_2_Services` in their URL address bar, their request gets redirected to `http://example.com/contact-us`, which will replace the other URL in their address bar and their browser will then request the resource at `http://example.com/contact-us` (the old URL is tossed out the window).

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=[0-9_]+_Contact-Us [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=[0-9_]+_Services [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /contact-us [L,R=301]
```

Of course, if you've got nothing at `http://example.com/contact-us`, the browser will just see a 404 error.

Comment: Yeah, I thought there was a way using .htaccess to rewrite pretty URLs. So that it drops all the mess and just uses the string.

There's nothing at http://example.com/contact-us, so it would just toss a 404.

Comment: @omyzach There's 2 things happening when URLs get changed, there's the client's end and the server's end, both are different. See the top of this answer for a quick explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273