# Mod_rewrite works but path is changed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, seo

I have urls like this index.php?section=products&id=12 and I want urls like this /products/shirt-12 (where shirt is the name of the product).

So I have a PHP script that, when you add a product, adds a line to .htaccess. Here is my .htaccess with 1 product added:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /products/shirt-12 /index.php?section=products&id=12
```

The thing is that when I write www.domain.com/product/shirt-12 in my browser, no scripts/images are included, I look into an image-not-loaded-square and it was trying to load the image from /products/images/img.jpg insted of /images/img.jpg. How can I solve this issue?
I tried DocumentRoot but I get a 500 error. What should I do?

**EDIT**: also if I put `/index.php?section=products&id=12` in my browser the url is not rewritten, it works like always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> thing is that when I write www.domain.com/product/shirt-12 in my browser, no scripts/images are included

This is because the relative URI base has changed. When you have links to images/css/scripts that are relative (i.e. they don't start with a `http://` or `/`) then the browser has to append a **base** to the front of it in order to make a request for the resource. WHen the browser goes to:

```
/index.php?section=products&id=12
```

The base URI is `/`, so any relative links it sees, it will simply append `/` to the beginning of them. But when the browser sees:

```
/product/shirt-12
```

The base URI is `/product/`, so any relative links it sees, it will append `/product/` to the beginning, and all your relative links will be broken.

You fix this by either changing all of your relative links to absolute links by adding a `/` in front of the URI. Or add this to the header of your page:

```
<base href="/">
```

> also if I put `/index.php?section=products&id=12` in my browser the url is not rewritten, it works like always.

Of course it's not rewritten, you don't have a rule for it. A rewrite rule works like this:

```
RewriteRule <match> <target> <flags>
```

Whatever incoming URI, if it matches the regex `<match>` it gets rewritten to `<target>`. That's it. There's not `<target>` back to an ambiguous regular expression (how in the world does that even work??). It doesn't magically change what's shown in browser URL address bars. It simply takes something that matches the regular expression, and *internally on the server* rewrites it to the `<target>`.

If you want to change what's in your browser, that's a completely different ordeal than your image paths.

Comment: I don't understand, with 

RewriteRule /products/shirt-12 /index.php?section=products&id=12

I don't redirect all traffic from /index.php?section=products&id=12 to /products/shirt-12? If not, how I needs to be written?

Comment: @DavidTG it doesn't have anything to do with this question, for an explanation see the top part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is instead of wasting hours on learning and creating mod_rewrite rules and trying to pitch perfect every url for your website why don't you take a super easy, super lightweight framework like Codeigniter http://codeigniter.com or Kohana http://kohanaframework.org and build your website on top of that

These frameworks provide a base, a foundation to build upon and get out of the way to leave you with infinite possibilities.