# URL rewrite and references to learn the apache mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I beg a pardon for quite a dumb question on url rewriting.

I have an url

https://example.com/?hash=3aa24be66484f1a39c72287fc994c7865e0a6126f1e678c94a1da5e2eb59bdb1

I have to configure .htaccess that is the following url would be a valid link
https://example.com/hash/3aa24be66484f1a39c72287fc994c7865e0a6126f1e678c94a1da5e2eb59bdb1

Thats it!

This is a first time I've met the url rewriting and could not find a good resource in web to start learning from zero. **Could you please give me an advise where to start?**

Thank you.

Comment: to many results lot of broken links

Comment: So you want someone to do the Googling for you and weed out the broken links? And SO is not a reference engine.

Comment: @EJP I thought this is called a "sharing of knowledge", but now it looks like threatening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation:

[Apache 2.2 mod_rewrite module reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

[Apache 2.2 rewrite guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/)

Next, use google: [apache mod_rewrite tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=apache+mod_rewrite+tutorial&oq=apache+mod_rewrite)

Your specific issue:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?hash/(.*)$ /?hash=$1 [L]
```

Also, to clarify what "rewrite" and "redirect" are [see the top part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273).

Comment: Thank you, simple and concise!