# URL Rewrite not working?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

Ive been wrecking my mind trying to figure out why my URL rewrites wont work!

Im currently using

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /profile.php?county=$1&name=$2&id=1 [L]
```

with no affect whatsoever, I have checked to see mod_rewrite is on which it is. If I use

```
RewriteRule ^rdr\.html http://www.google.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Im redirected to Google so I know it must definitly be something im doing.

The url im trying to rewrite is...

```
http://www.mysite.com/profile.php?county=Cheshire&name=Martin-Mack&id=2
```

Comment: You might try replacing ([^/]*) with (.*) and also ensuring that the URLs you are trying to rewrite have a trailing slash.

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite `/x/y/` into `/profile.php?county=x&name=y&id=1`, or the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?county=$1&name=$2&id=1
```

**profile.php**

```
<h1>Profile</h1>
<?php
echo "County: " . $_GET['county'] . "<br>";
echo "Name: " . $_GET['name'] . "<br>";
echo "Id: " . $_GET['id'];
```

This URL: `http://localhost/tests/htaccess_test/Cheshire/Martin-Mack`

Produced this HTML:

```
<h1>Profile</h1>
County: Cheshire<br>Name: Martin-Mack<br>Id: 1
```

[image: Rendering in Opera]

Tested on Apache 2.2.21 and PHP 5.3.10.

---

In my test I've put both files in `http://localhost/tests/htaccess_test/`, but you can put them where you want; they only need to be in the same folder.

In your case for example, you should put the files in the root of your website, so that when you access to `http://www.yoursite.com/Cheshire/Martin-Mack`, the redirect will work.

If you still can't get it to work, try adding `RewriteBase /` right after `RewriteEngine On`.

Full example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?county=$1&name=$2&id=1
```

---

**Update:** In your original code, the `id` parameter is static. To get it working too, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?county=$1&name=$2&id=$3
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @Simone however I still cant get it too work, im not sure if im understanding this whole concept correctly. The URL I visit is site.com/profile.php?county=Cheshire&name=Liam-Gallagher&id=1

This link is generated from my php using php variables

Comment: My example works differently. Try to visit `site.com/Cheshire/Martin-Mack` and you should be *silently* redirected to `profile.php?county=Cheshire&name=Liam-Gallagher&id=1`

Comment: Sort of works @Simone, my problem however is the "ID" variable now, Its always 1, whereas it should change for each user?

Comment: This has stopped the rewrite from working at all now @Simone

Comment: No it just says page not found, whereas intitially it would redirect to the page but with th ewrong ID

Comment: let's continue in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18398/rewrite-issues)

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact answer to the question, but perhaps useful in general; you can switch on rewrite logging which can help track down issues.

In [Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog):

```
RewriteLog com.example_rewrite.log 
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

The syntax has changed slightly in [Apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging).

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is very close.

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?county=$1&name=$2&id=1 [L]
```

- I think Mr. Samuel Cook touched on your problem --- your rule requires a trailing slash.  Adding the `?` after the trailing slash in the rule allow both URLs with it and those without.
- Also, the modified rule uses `+`s instead of your `*`s, because the `*` modifier will match an empty string, and would likely cause a redirect loop.

Sidenote: **Use a 302 redirect when you're testing!**  Your browser will "memorize" 301 redirects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @smhmic, It still doen't work however :/

Comment: @Liam Oftentimes, the carat (`^`) at the beginning of a rule makes it match for me.  It am still troubleshooting why, because the rule should work with the carat and is not always safe to remove ... but try removing it just to see.

Answer (score 0):

The top part of [this answer clarifies how URLs get *rewritten* and *redirected*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273). There's 2 completely different things going on there.

To change a URL like `/profile.php?county=foo&name=bar&id=1234` to the nicer looking variation, you need to match against the actual request and redirect the browser:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /profile\.php\?county=([^&]+)&name=([^&]+)&id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3/%4/? [L,R=301]
```

Note that the **id** needs to also be part of the URL (backreferenced via `%4`). This makes it so when someone types in their browser the URL: `http://mysite.com/profile.php?county=Cheshire&name=Martin-Mack&id=2`, they get externally redirected to `http://mysite.com/Cheshire/Martin-Mack/2/`, changing the URL in the address bar.

Then in order to internally rewrite the nicer looking URL and route it back to the php script:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /profile.php?county=$1&name=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

This does the reverse, but only internally so that the URL in the browser's address bar remains unchanged while the content is served from `profile.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If your rewrite is in  or htaccess, it will be comparing against "profile.php" so the / in the middle can never match, much less the second slash at the end.