# .htaccess convert a url parameter in folders

Tags: .htaccess

I try to convert a url parameter in folders using RewriteRule.
Anyone can help me?.

**Origin:** search.php?term=red&cat=colors
**Destination:** /search/red/colors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top part of [this answer clarifies how URLs get *rewritten* and *redirected*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273). Using "convert" is not really clear, as there's 2 completely different things that can happen.

To change a URL like `/search.php?term=red&cat=colors` to the nicer looking variation, you need to match against the actual request and redirect the browser:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /search\.php\?term=([^&]+)&cat=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /search/%2/%3/? [L,R=301]
```

This makes it so when someone types in their browser the URL: `http://mysite.com/search.php?term=red&cat=colors`, they get externally redirected to `http://mysite.com/search/red/colors`, changing the URL in the address bar.

Then in order to internally rewrite the nicer looking URL and route it back to the php script:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?term=$1&cat=$2 [L]
```

This does the reverse, but only internally so that the URL in the browser's address bar remains unchanged while the content is served from `search.php`. You can do one or the other depending on what your need is, or you can do both if you need this to happen in both directions.