# url rewriting in php localhost with .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, apache2

I want to rewrite url
from

```
http://localhost/Ent/Movie/Info.php?year=2011&movie=any_movie
```

to

```
http://localhost/Ent/Movie/Info/2011/any_movie
```

I have tried many code in .htaccess,like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /Ent/Movie/
RewriteRule ^Info/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ Info.php?year=$1&movie=$2 [L]
```

here note that,my .htaccess file is in the root of website.

is my .htaccess location wrong **or** code inside .htaccess?

Comment: http://localhost/Ent/Movie/Info.php?year=2011&movie=any_movie is not rewriting to http://localhost/Ent/Movie/Info/2011/any_movie

Comment: I think if the rewrite code is ok then : localhost/Ent/Movie/Info/2011/any_movie will return the result. and localhost/Ent/Movie/Info.php?year=2011&movie=any_movie will not automatically rewrite.

Comment: did you enable mod_rewrite locally? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: Be sure to add NC so it is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To externally redirect a browser to the nicer looking URL (without the query string):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /Ent/Movie/Info\.php\?year=([^&]+)&movie=([^&\ ]+)([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /Ent/Movie/Info/%2/%3?%4 [L,R=301]
```

Then internally rewrite it back

```
RewriteRule ^/?Ent/Movie/Info/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /Ent/Movie/Info.php?year=$1&movie=$2 [L,QSA]
```

These rules go in the document root, and they'd go right under:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
```

Comment: what does it mean "externally" and "internally"?

Comment: @Downloadmore External means the response sent to the browser or whoever sent the request is "What you want has moved, go over here for it", and it's up to the browser to go fetch it. It is external to the server, the server responds with a redirect and that's the end of story. Internally means the browser sends a request, the server internally (all within the server) rewrites the request and sends it back through its internal URL processing pipeline, maybe at the end of it all, it sends content to the browser, who knows nothing about all the internal redirection

Comment: @Downloadmore Also see the top part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^Info/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ Info.php?year=$1&movie=$2
```

would match rewrite in the opposite direction, so you need to reverse the logic to something like:

```
RewriteRule ^Info.php?year=([0-9]+)&movie=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ Info/$1/$2
```

First is what you are trying to match, second argument is the pattern you want to produce.
See the [mod_rewrite tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex).

Comment: @Petr what should be location of .htaccess file means either in root locaton or Ent folder or in Movie folder

Comment: Don't know - check the documentation. :)
My guess is, that if you put it into Movie, you could get rid of RewriteBase - but it's just a guess.

Comment: You can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule