# Using .htaccess to redirect example.com/about.php to example.com/about/

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I recently switched over my website to Wordpress. My old files were www.example.com/about.php and now its www.example.com/about/. I need to redirect incoming links from the .php extension to just the / for ALL my pages preferably using .htaccess.

What I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Whats in my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I guess I don't know where I'd put it in my .htaccess file either.
Thanks!

Comment: Good. Now that you have formulated what you need, you can make it. Then, when you get stuck, we're happy to help you get unstuck, but we're not going to do this for you.

Comment: Okey, so now we have the code. Now you should tell us what it does differently from what you want...

Comment: Its not doing anything, which is the problem. Incoming links that have the old /about.php extension are not redirecting to /about/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have does **not** redirect anything. It takes a request that might be for a php file and internally appends the `.php` extension. Nothing happens on the browser because you've not told it to do anything. This is a 2 step process here. See the top part of [this answer for a short explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273).

In order to redirect, you need to match against the incoming request, not the URI (which could have been rewritten be previous rules or iterations):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ /(.*)\.php($|\ )
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [L,R=301]
```

So when someone types `http://www.example.com/about.php` in their browser's URL address bar, the request will look like:

```
GET /about.php HTTP/1.1
```

and the **%2** backreferences `about` and redirects the browser to `http://www.example.com/about/` (note the trailing slash) and the address bar changes.

What happens then is the browser *makes ANOTHER request* but this time for `http://www.example.com/about/` and the server gets the URI `/about/`. Now you need your rule to internally rewrite it back to the php file. Unfortunately, your rule doesn't handle the trailing slash, so you need something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

These would all go **before** your wordpress rules. The wordpress rules route everything to `index.php` and that would wreck any URI you are trying to rewrite.

Comment: The redirect worked perfectly, but now I can't login to my dashboard on Wordpress.

Comment: @megann42 the wp-admin is a special case, you probably don't want to be redirecting those. See the edit for the first set of rules that exclude wp-admin

Comment: Okay! Works now, I did have to change !wp-admin to !wp-login. Thank you so much!

Comment: is there a way to exclude a certain folder, for instance a contact form folder? My custom contact form from a plugin isn't processing

Answer (score 0):

You are doing things the wrong way around. You are actually rewriting urls that end end without php to files that do end in .php.

You'd need to do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ $1/ [NC]
```

I also removed the check if the file you are redirecting to exists as well as the [L] flag, because it's likely that wordpress is also doing its own rewriting, which means that you don't want this to be the last rule processed and that you won't be able to find the file on the filesystem.

Comment: Would it go before the #End wordpress in my htaccess file above? I'm sorry, I just don't know much about this.

Comment: @user1809706 Before. You'd want to do this before wordpress gets its hands on it and possibly rewrites it (to be specific, it rewrites everything to `index.php` so if you put it after, it would never match because that file exists (I hope))