# redirecting url and showing the short url on the adress bar

Tags: .htaccess

I've seen a lot of sites doing this but haven't found a guide to explain this.
I have this .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
```

It redirects site.com/user/1 to site.com/profile.php?id=1
but when it redirects I want the user to see in his adress bar the shortened url (site.com/user/1)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite is internal logic of the server, i.e. the browser requested for the long URL you see in the address bar, and the HTTP server routed it to the shorter one. If you want the browser to show the shorter URL, you will need to use `Redirect` instead of `Rewrite`.

Note that with redirect, the page will be slower to load, as the server returns the redirection response to the browser, which then requests the page once again.

Comment: Thanks, So is it `Redirect ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1` ? and do i put it inside `<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
`?

Comment: What server are you using -- is it Apache?
If so, the directive you should use is `RedirectMatch`. It has nothing to do with the module `mod_rewrite` anymore, so you don't need to put it inside the conditional clause.

Comment: Yes, apache. I've just tried `RedirectMatch art/(.*) /article.php?a=$1` and again, it redirects to the full adress and changes the adress on the adress bar. can it have something to do with the apache settings of the server? thanks for your help

Comment: That should have worked. Check if you have `mod_alias` enabled. Also, since this is an external redirect (executed by the browser), you can debug it in the browser: for example, if you use Chrome, you can see in the debug window (Ctrl-Shift-J), under the *Network* tab, all HTTP requests that were executed. Look there for the redirect response (3XX), and in it, for the `Location:` header. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of sources on how to do this. This is the first one I got when I googled it.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

Comment: i found this one to, and I'm using the same code as they do but it's not keeping the shortened url in the adress bar. That's why I asked

Answer (score 0):

A rule works like:

```
RewriteRule <pattern_A> <target_B>
```

It **always** works from `<pattern_A>` to  `<target_B>`, never the other way around, there's no "linking" of the 2 requests by this rule. The [top part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711948/851273) addresses the 2 different things that happens when "URLs get changed for another URL".

The rule that you have takes a URL without a query string and internally rewrites it to a php file with a query string. The browser doesn't see this happen, it's "behind the scenes". When you say you want the address bar to show the URL that doesn't have the query string, you'd first be going to some URL that's something else, and that "something else" URL needs to externally redirect the browser. So under the rules that you already have:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /profile\.php\?id=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /users/%1? [L,R=301]
```

That matches against a request string, not the request URI (which gets changed along the URL processing pipeline and the rewrite engine), extracts the ID, and *redirects the browser* to the new URL without the query string by using the `R=301` flag.

You really need to change *all of your content* so that they use the cleaner looking URLs instead of relying on a very cumbersome and inefficient way of redirecting the browser, then internally rewriting *back* to the original URL.