# IIS url rewrite Error 404.0 [edited]

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, webmatrix, url-rewrite-module

I want:
`domain.com/example`
to target:
`domain.com/folder/example.cshtml`

Can anyone help me with the rewrite rule for it?
Every suggestion is much appreciated :)

---

*I have edited the question so that it actually focuses on what is important.*

Comment: Do you get a 404 when hitting `domain.com/example.cshtml` from your browser?

Comment: @cheesemacfly Yes, though I was thinking in the wrong direction, vice-versa to be precise. The code in the question doesn't make sense though.

Comment: Yes, I guess you should first fix your 404 error then :)

Comment: Well, you see.. the error is caused by the very code that I can't get working. So finding a solution for the rewrite will fix the error.

Comment: But you said that the url `domain.com/example.cshtml` gives you a 404 error right? So when you hit `domain.com/folder/example.cshtml` it is redirected to `domain.com/example.cshtml` giving you a 404 error

Comment: Oh, I see. No sorry, the error is not what's important. The rewrite rule is, which I can't get to work. I have edited the question so you'll get what i really meant.

Comment: Seems like you have asked 3 times the same question. Are you sure you know what you want? :)

Comment: I just want a rule so when you request: `domain.com/example` you actually get `domain.com/folder/example.cshtml`. It is much better explained in the other question of mine you commented on.

Answer (score 0):

why aren't you using mod-rewrite?

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /folder/example.cshtml
RewriteRule ^$ /example.cshtml [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^example.cshtml /folder/example.cshtml [L]
```

Sometimes you need to mess around with the slashes a bit

Comment: The "not found" error is because you are re-directing to a directory structure that doesn't exist.  re-writing isn't just how the address appears in your browser: it actually affects where the client looks for the file.

A great tutorial about re-writing can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709634/convert-original-url-to-friendly-url/11711948#11711948.

Comment: Can't use mod-rewrite with IIS servers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can't be done the way i want it.
I'll have to move `example.cshtml` to the root directory.

Comment: sorry, I forgot that you were on .net.  I don't think the issue is a re-write issue, but instead has to do with how you configured the view associated with example.cshtml.