# Problems with mod_rewrite dynamic URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I've made my own blog on my domain and for displaying the articles I'm using a dynamic URL to display the article content on the page.

An example how it looks now:
http://www.blog.madetocreate.nl/artikel.php?id=47

Now I've searched for a mod_rewrite method for days, but everything I tried fails. The service provider told me mod_rewrite is enabled and I only have to access it with a .htaccess file.

The file I have at this moment contains the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^artikel/([^/]+)/?$ artikel.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I want to get the url to look like this:

http://www.blog.madetocreate.nl/artikel/47/title-of-the-post-here/

But so far I can't even get managed to get the first `"artikel/47/"`

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The regex should look like the following:

```
^artikel/([0-9]+)/([\w-]*)$
```

Which gives you:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^artikel/([0-9]+)/([\w-]*)$ artikel.php?id=$1 [L]
```

`([0-9]+)` matches 1 or more number

`([\w-]*)` matches 0 or more word character and `-`, meaning that you can have both `artikel/47/` and `artikel/47/title-of-the-post-here`

Comment: Well, the point is that I just uploaded this new code, and when I open blog.madetocreate.nl/artikel.php?id=47 , the url doesn't turn up as artikel/47/titel-of-post/. Am I not understanding mod_rewrite at all or something?

Comment: A RewriteRule won't redirect you, it just tells apache to interpret the address `artikel/47/titel-of-post` as `artikel.php?id=47`. You should take a look a this post explaining the differences between those two concepts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709634/convert-original-url-to-friendly-url/11711948#11711948